# How to change a material with python in blender?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials, interface

I have a basic panel script with 3 buttons made with an enum. Those buttons are meant to change two materials of an object e.g. the 'silver' button would change the materials to the silver materials etc. *Update* I put one of those lines into the console directly and it worked just fine, so I guess it's a matter of where I put those codes into, does anyone know where it should be?

This is what I tried:

```
D = bpy.data

if colors == 'Gold':
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[0].material = D.material['Gold']
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[9].material = D.material['Gold Apple Logo']
elif colors == 'Silver':
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[0].material = D.material['Silver']
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[9].material = D.material['Silver']
elif colors == 'Space Grey':
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[0].material = D.material['Space Grey']
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[9].material = D.material['Space Grey Apple Logo']
```

There were no errors, but it just doesn't do anything...

Here is my full code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import (Menu, PropertyGroup)
from bpy.props import (BoolProperty, FloatProperty, EnumProperty)

def update_after_enum(self, context):
    D = bpy.data

    if colors == 'Gold':
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['Gold']
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[9].material = D.materials['Gold Apple Logo']
elif colors == 'Silver':
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['Silver']
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[9].material = D.materials['Silver']
elif colors == 'Space Grey':
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['Space Grey']
    D.objects['Macbook'].material_slots[9].material = D.materials['Space Grey Apple Logo']


def common_update(self, context, origin):
    obj = bpy.data.objects.get("Macbook")
    if not obj:
        return

    if origin == 'isight_camera_indicator':
        obj["00_iSight Camera Indicator"] = getattr(self, origin)

        node_tree = bpy.data.materials['iSight Camera Indicator'].node_tree
        node = node_tree.nodes["Emission"]

        if getattr(self, origin):
            emission_value = 5.0
        else:
            emission_value = 0.0

        nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = emission_value

    elif origin == 'dirt_and_dust':
        obj["01_Dirt and Dust"] = getattr(self, origin)
    elif origin == 'menubar_and_dock':
        obj["02_Menubar and Dock"] = getattr(self, origin)
    elif origin == 'screen_rotation':
        obj["03_Screen Rotation"] = getattr(self, origin)


class IgnitProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    isight_camera_indicator = BoolProperty(
        name = "iSight Camera Indicator",
        description = "Toggles the iSight Camera Indicator ON and OFF",
        default = False,
        update = lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, 'isight_camera_indicator')
    )

    dirt_and_dust = BoolProperty(
        name = "Dirt and Dust",
        description = "Toggles the Dirt and Dust ON and OFF",
        default = False,
        update = lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, 'dirt_and_dust')
    )

    menubar_and_dock = BoolProperty(
        name = "Menubar and Dock",
        description = "Toggles the Menubar and Dock ON and OFF",
        default = False,
        update = lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, 'menubar_and_dock')
    )

    screen_rotation = FloatProperty(
        name = "Screen Rotation",
        description = "Rotates the screen",
        default = 0.0,
        min = 0.0,
        max = 1.0,
        update = lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, 'screen_rotation')
    )

    #MacBook Colors
    colors = EnumProperty(
        name = "MacBook Colors",
        description = "Changes the color of the MacBook",
        items = [
            ("Silver", "Silver", "Silver"),
            ("Gold", "Gold", "Gold"),
            ("Space Grey", "Space Grey", "Space Grey")
        ],
        update = update_after_enum
    )

class IGLayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "MacBook Controller"
    bl_idname = "object_mode.macbook_controller"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text = "Main Features:")

        scene = context.scene
        split = layout.split()
        scene = context.scene
        camera = scene.camera.data

        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "isight_camera_indicator")
        col.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "dirt_and_dust")

        # Second Column
        col = split.column()
        col.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "menubar_and_dock")
        col.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "screen_rotation")

        # MacBook Colors
        layout.label(text = "MacBook Color:")

        row = layout.row(align=True)

        row.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "colors", expand = True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=IgnitProperties)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister__module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.ignit_panel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: The indenting was just from putting the code into here, its fine in the actual script in blender, and as for the materials, I tested it in the console directly and it worked fine...

Comment: Ok, I put the self.colors in and it worked fine! Gee I really wish coding for blender were like coding in unity!

Comment: Oh no I was referring to C#, in fact more so to the IDE, monodevelop, it works so much better than a text editor!

Comment: Yeah, Blender would benefit from a built in IDE, a mix between a REPL (console) and a TextEditor. No argument there :)  I tend to use SublimeText3 with snippets of templates / and a [custom set of templates](https://github.com/zeffii/x_templates)

Comment: Hmm, that's a pretty good resource! I do you know if Monodevelop can code with python, does it know the python syntaxing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your first snippet references `bpy.data.material`, but it should be `bpy.data.materials`. It is plural; think of it as a collection of all materials in the .blend.
2. Secondly the `colors` variable isn't global, but part of the PropertyGroup and must be referenced using `self.colors`.

your update function most likely would be written less verbose this way:

```
def update_after_enum(self, context):

    objects = bpy.data.objects
    materials = bpy.data.materials

    macbook = objects.get('Macbook')
    if not macbook:
        return

    slots = macbook.material_slots
    colors = self.colors

    if colors == 'Gold':
        slots[0].material = materials['Gold']
        slots[9].material = materials['Gold Apple Logo']
    elif colors == 'Silver':
        slots[0].material = materials['Silver']
        slots[9].material = materials['Silver']
    elif colors == 'Space Grey':
        slots[0].material = materials['Space Grey']
        slots[9].material = materials['Space Grey Apple Logo']
```

Then a bit of nitpicking. The last section I would go even further and write it without the if-elif-elif and use the colors property directly.

Assuming you have the following materials in the .blend

```
- 'Gold'
- 'Gold Apple Logo'
- 'Silver'
- 'Silver Apple Logo'
- 'Space Grey'
- 'Space Grey Apple Logo'
```

code:

```
    if self.colors in {'Gold', 'Silver', 'Space Grey'}:
        slots[0].material = materials[self.colors]
        slots[9].material = materials[self.colors + ' Apple Logo']
```